# Form error message not showing

Tags: php, forms

My form gives me a success message when all required fields are filled and i click send.
But no error message or success message when a field is missing. Anyone spot the error?
I have no idea about PHP so be kind!

Please help, I need this by tomorrow!

```
<?php

function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "Wir freuen uns sehr leid, aber es gab Fehler(s) mit dem Formular, das Sie   vorgelegt gefunden. ";
    echo "Diese Fehler werden unten angezeigt.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Bitte gehen Sie zurück und diese Fehler zu beheben.<br /><br />";
    die();
 }


if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "xxxx@xxx.xxx";
    $email_subject = "Nachricht von Website Kontaktformular";


    // validation expected data exists
    if(empty($_POST['vorname']) || empty($_POST['nachname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['nachricht'])) {
        died('Es tut uns leid, aber es scheint ein Problem mit dem Formular, das Sie vorgelegt werden.');       
    }

    $vorname = $_POST['vorname']; // required
    $nachname = $_POST['nachname']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // geändert
    $telefon = $_POST['telefon']; // not required
    $nachricht = $_POST['nachricht']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'Die Email Adresse, die Sie eingeben, nicht gültig zu sein scheint.<br />';
    }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";


    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$vorname)) {
        $error_message .= 'Die Vorname Sie eingeben, nicht gültig zu sein scheint.<br />';
    }
    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$nachname)) {
        $error_message .= 'Die Nachname Sie eingeben, nicht gültig zu sein scheint.<br />';
    }
    if(strlen($nachricht) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'Die Nachricht, die Sie eingeben, nicht gültig zu sein scheint.<br    />';
    }
    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }
    $email_message = "Formular einzelheiten unten.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Vorname: ".clean_string($vorname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Nachname: ".clean_string($nachname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telefon: ".clean_string($telefon)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Nachricht: ".clean_string($nachricht)."\n";


    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <!-- place your own success html below -->
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="font-size:1.125em; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:#a6bf48; margin-top:90px; text-align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:960px; padding:20px;">
            Vielen Dank für ihre Nachricht! Ich werde mich sobald wie möglich mit ihnen in Verbindung setzen.<br><br>
            <a href="psychologin.html" style="color:#FFF">Zurück</a>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: You may want to add ini_set('display_errors',1) to the top of your script.  This should make PHP output any errors.

Comment: "Please help, I need this by tomorrow!" Uhhhm you started too late :P_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, if you don't fill the email text field, then nothing will appear what-so-ever, so you have that in the wrong place - try changing it from:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])){
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
```

**Update**

<del>Further more, upon tiding up your code, you have written `died()` a few times - this should be `die()`</del>

Comment: The script defines the `died()` function in the beginning.

Comment: Haha - of course it does - just a bit confusing I guess, especially when everything else is German-looking...

Comment: Yea sorry about that, I would prefer English too!

Comment: Any luck working yet? Remember to accept answers - you'll get points and in turn more people wil help you here at StackOverflow :)

Comment: No luck still, I think it's to do with die & died, which goes where?

Comment: Try adding an `exit();` after your `died()` functions - will completely stop anymore output from appearing on screen (which I gather is happening from your other comments)

Comment: it's when i change the last die to died `<?php
}
died();
?>` that i get my error massage as wanted, but also get it alongside the success message

Comment: I see... change it to `<?php } else { died(); } ?>` - so this error message will appear if `$_POST['email']` is empty

Answer (score 0):

MrJ is right, you shouldn't base your decision point on 1 field.  You may want to consider replacing all `emptys()`s with `isset()`.  According to the php manual, empty won't kick off an error if the variable isn't defined, and that appears to be what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If I replace all empty() with isset() I get the error message which is great. But I  also get it when all fields are filled in!

Comment: Sorry, I mean I get the error message when required fields are not filled, which is what I want, but I get the same message when everything is filled in correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant.  It's still important to see the error message it's giving when you think everything is filled in correctly.  It might identify what fields are missing or show that the problem isn't with a missing field at all.

Comment: I get my message error correctly now. However on sending correctly I get both success message and error message! Error massage simply says there are errors in the form.

Comment: @user1207682 Happy to hear it. Grüß Gott

Comment: Seeing an error message and success message simultaneously after sending a form isn't a good thing surely...

Comment: "Wir freuen uns sehr leid, aber es gab Fehler(s) mit dem Formular, das Sie vorgelegt gefunden. Diese Fehler werden unten angezeigt.

Bitte gehen Sie zurück und diese Fehler zu beheben."

Comment: it's when i change the last die to died `<?php } died(); ?>` that i get my error massage as wanted, but also get it alongside the success message